# accurate progress bar to update to the user. vb.net

Tags: vb.net

hi i am doing some copied work and made a progress bar to update to the user.  i get the number of files which i copied which i name counter below. And every counter/3, they will give a text.However, i got a problem, the progress bar is not accurate.even in the maximum I think the reason is beacuse i add the progressbar 50 every time and the number of count could be like 297,189, which is not the times of 50. 
Can anyone help cheers.

```
        Dim counter = Directory.GetFiles(fileToCopy, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
        ProgressBar1.Increment(50)
        Dim fileSize = GetFolderSize(fileToCopy)
        If ProgressBar1.Value < Math.Ceiling(counter / 3) And ProgressBar1.Value > 0 Then
            Label5.Text = ("1/3 of files already Copied")
        End If
        If ProgressBar1.Value < Math.Ceiling(counter * 2 / 3) And ProgressBar1.Value > Math.Ceiling(counter / 3) Then
            Label5.Text = ("2/3 of files already Copied")
        End If
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = counter


        If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Label5.Text = ("Copied is all done")
```

Comment: You should look in to background workers for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at AsyncMethodHandlers

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29925/Responsive-UIs-for-WPF-Applications-Using-Asynchro

This should get you on the right track.  It has vb.net code as well.